# Error while using fgets in C

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I'm writing a small program to check how the function [strcasestr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasestr) works.

What the code below does:

1. Asks the user to enter a line of text.
   Example first input: `blah bla blah blah the Word we are looking for.`
   Example second input: `Word`
2. What the program should print is: `Word we are looking for.`
3. But it gives me a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

I suspect I'm using `fgets()` incorrectly. When I run the program using `scanf` to read the input (of course entering the first input withoutspaces) it works and gives me the expected output.

Any idea what's causing the segmentation fault error? How to correct this?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define max_buff 1000
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char *answer;
//char * strcasestr (const char *haystack, const char *needle);

void strip_crlf(char* s);

void strip_crlf(char* s)
{
    char* p = strpbrk(s, "\r\n");
    if (p) *p = '\0';
}

int main(){
  char fname[max_buff+1];
  char lname[max_buff+1];

  printf("Enter the line of text you are searching for ");
  //scanf("%s", fname);

  fgets(fname,max_buff,stdin);
  //printf("%s",fname);
  strip_crlf(fname);

  printf("Enter the search term ");
  //scanf("%s", lname);
  fgets(lname,max_buff,stdin);
  strip_crlf(lname);
  //printf("%s",lname);
  if((answer=strcasestr(fname,lname))!=NULL){

  // printf("now we have something in answer ");
    printf("%s\n",answer);
  }
  else
      printf(" strcasestr failed\n");

}
```

EDITED: to reflect suggestions made in comments/answers below. the program now prints:

```
 strcasestr failed
```

...Ughh.

Edit2: program works now. thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: FYI, you don't need `max_buff+1`, since `fgets()` subtracts 1 from the `size` argument.

Comment: Have you checked that `answer` is not `NULL`?

Comment: @Barmar   ah yes.forgot to change it back b4 posting i on here.
no i havnt. but strcasestr would do that onlyif it couldnt find a match. with these inputs it should be able to find a match?

Comment: You should check that each `fgets()` succeeds, officially. You can get away with not doing so while you're typing input, but you should make your program does not fail because of early EOF. And you should check what `strcasestr()` returns. It's also a good idea when debugging a problem to print the inputs you actually got so you can check that what you got is what you expected. For example: `printf("Search for <<%s>> in <<%s>>\n", lname, fname);` would show that there is a newline in the searched-for string (needle), as well as a newline at the end of the searched string (haystack).

Comment: Too much copy'n'paste; you strip `fname` twice and `lname` not at all. Also, there's no reason to make `answer` a global variable, nor a reason to include `<ctype.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` in the current code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ops! its getting late here :S. Thanks for the catch! :D program works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking for a failure from `strcasestr()`, which IS failing, because you're not stripping `\n` or `\r\n` from your inputs.

The only search that will succeed is if it matches the end of the first input.

To strip CRLF:

```
void strip_crlf(char* s)
{
    char* p = strpbrk(s, "\r\n");
    if (p) *p = '\0';
}
```

Then just `strip_crlf(fname);` after `fgets`. Same for `lname`.

Comment: i just checked for the failure case and it indeed does fail or some reason..dono why... ill try the above code and get back to you.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the comparison succeeded before trying to print the result:

```
if (answer) {
    printf("%s\n", answer);
} else {
    printf("No match\n");
}
```

The reason the comparison is failing is probably because `fgets()` includes the newline in the buffer, but `scanf()` doesn't. You'll need to remove the newline at the end of the string if you don't want it to mess up the comparison.